# Двоеточие в предложении "Самыми распространенными препаратами являются(:) ..."

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

*Самыми распространенными препаратами при лечении венозных заболеваний ног являются: Детралекс, Венарус и Флебодиа.*

Нужно ли в этом предложении двоеточие?

Comment: В этом предложении, во-первых. А потом, на чём основаны сомнения?

Comment: Обиходные названия лекарств пишутся с маленькой буквы без кавычек, а названия соответствующих торговых марок - с большой буквы в кавычках (в специализированных текстах). См. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=207664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предложениях с перечислением возможна постановка двоеточия даже в том случае, если нет обобщающего слова. Этот знак препинания для читателя является сигналом о том, что далее следует перечисление.

1. Обычно известные иностранные названия лекарств (в переводе на русский язык) пишутся со строчной буквы.
2. Предложение лучше немного перестроить, чтобы акцент на собственно препараты находился в самом конце.

**При лечении венозных заболеваний ног самыми распространенными препаратами являются: детралекс, венарус и флебодиа.**

[Где ставится двоеточие](http://gramatik.ru/gde-stavitsya-dvoetochie/)

Answer (score 3):

> Нужно ли в этом предложение двоеточие?

**Не нужно. Но и вариант с двоеточием тоже не будет ошибкой.**

См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

> **§ 33.** Если обобщающее слово предшествует ряду однородных членов, то после обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие…
>
> <...>
>
> **Примечание.** В текстах деловых и научных двоеточие может ставиться перед перечислением и при отсутствии обобщающего слова: *На собрании
>   **присутствовали:** студенты, аспиранты, преподаватели.* В других
>   случаях двоеточие обычно отсутствует: *Великие гуманисты того
>   времени подняли голос против турок. В защиту **выступили** Виктор Гюго,
>   Чарлз Дарвин, Оскар Уайльду Лев Толстой, Федор Достоевский, Д. И.
>   Менделеев, В. М. Гаршин, В. В. Верещагин* (Сол.).

Answer (score 0):

1. То, что вариант без двоеточия корректен, не вызывает сомнения. Допустим и вариант с двоеточием. Но чисто интуитивно: если уж ставить двоеточие, то я бы убрал союз *и*, с ним такая конструкция режет глаз.
2. Как писать названия лекарств:

   > Обратите внимание: при употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия лекарственных средств следует писать с прописной буквы в кавычках: «Арбидол», «Инфлювак», «Афлубин», «Фервекс», а в бытовом употреблении – со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: выпить фервекс, принять виагру. Также пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек некоторые названия лекарств, вошедшие в широкий обиход вследствие многолетнего употребления (валидол, анальгин, аспирин). ([Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2))

Comment: М_Г: _В Нацкорпусе не удалось найти ни одного вхождения слова **являются** с последующим двоеточием._ === **?????**  См. http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%FF%E2%EB%FF%F2%FC%F1%FF&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=bcolon&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо! Как-то не так искал. Я исправлю ответ.